# what is the variance of this? (random variables)

Tags: probability, statistics, problem-solving

Can anyone here tell me how can I do this: X and Y are two random variable and W = 5X-4Y+50. Knowing that the variance of X is 99 and the variance of Y is 81 then what is the variance of W?

Comment: Have you seen formulaes about $V(aX+b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are two reals ?

Comment: yes, but just with one random variable (X) not with two (X and Y)

Comment: Do you have any assomptions on $X$ and $Y$ ? (like independance ?). As reminder : $V(aX+b)=a^2V(X)$ and $V(X+Y)=V(X)+V(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independant

Comment: it just says that X and Y are independent

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? In that case @Atmos's comment is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independant,

$$V\left(W\right)=V\left(5X-4Y+50\right)=V\left(5X\right)+V\left(-4Y+50\right)=5^2V\left(X\right)+\left(-4\right)^2V\left(Y\right)$$

Comment: thanks! I have not seen this formula in class yet, so maybe I'll see it later.

Comment: You might have seen a formula linked to covariance, which is $0$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independant